# How to read the circuit to drive the numerical value of Vgs1?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

b) How do we know the numerical value of Vgs1? can you show me the exact mash?

Comment: Thank you for bringing your homework problem here to electronics.stackexchange.  In general, if you're doing homework, we ask you to *show your work*.  If you're absolutely all the way stuck, tell us how far you got, and give us your guess at what's holding you back.  Please edit your question to show how far you've gotten.

Comment: Found the answer! In large signal analysis the alternating voltage source is 0

Answer (score 1):

When doing DC analysis (large signal analysis), you remove all AC sources. That means replacing AC voltage sources with shorts. (AC current sources would be open. It is like replacing the source with its ideal internal resistance)

So in the DC model transistor's gate is connected through Rs to the ground. There is no current flowing to the gate, so the voltage drop across Rs is zero. That means the voltage at the gate is 0V (ground). Vss is -1.25V. Vgs is the difference between the voltage at the gate and Vss, which indeed is 0-1.25=1.25V.